# macport selfupdate not working

Tags: xcode, macos, rsync, macports

```
macbookpro:~ eistrati$ port -v
MacPorts 2.1.2

macbookpro:~ eistrati$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 4.5.2
Build version 4G2008a

macbookpro:~ eistrati$ sudo port -d selfupdate
DEBUG: Copying /Users/eistrati/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist to /opt/local/var/macports/home/Library/Preferences
DEBUG: MacPorts sources location: /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
rsync: failed to connect to rsync.macports.org: Connection refused (61)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/clientserver.c(105) [receiver=2.6.9]
Command failed: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base.tar /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
Exit code: 10
DEBUG: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed
   while executing
"macports::selfupdate [array get global_options] base_updated"
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed
```

Ideas? Please help!

Comment: Same issue as this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446923/macports-selfupdate

Comment: No, I've checked that post and nothing related

Comment: Perhaps it was a temporary problem on the server side.

Comment: can you run `port -d sync` sync in debug mode and see what it does ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not behind a firewall? Have you read https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#selfupdatefails ?